# is there a way to scrape a JavaScript page without selenium in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

is there a way to scrape JS-rendered web page with python beautifulsoup or lxml without selenium?

thanx

Comment: Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python

Answer (score -1):

you can use requests_html module as alternative, it is pretty simple

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://stackexchange.com/sites")

html = resp.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

option_tags = soup.find_all("option")
```

in case you want to get deeper into it, just google the module

Comment: Won't help with a Javascript-rendered page.